# How to check if an array of object contains an overlap?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following array:

```
[
 {start: "0", end: "3"}, 
 {start: "4", end: "6"},
 {start: "2", end: "8"}
]
```

as you can see the third object overlap the first two interval. For this purpose I created the following function:

```
checkOverlap = function(o1, o2){
  return ((o1.end - o2.start) >= 0 && (o2.end - o1.start) >= 0) ? true : false;
}
```

I wrote this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
   for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
      if(this.checkOverlap(array[i], array[x])){
         throw new Error("overlap detected");
      }
   }
}
```

but this will generate an error also when there are no overlap

how can I iterate over the array and compare each index to see if at least one object interval overlap another object interval?

Comment: Use two nested loops? (note that your question title is misleading, your issue isn't how to check for an overlap, it's about how to compare every array element with every other element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are checking each item with its self as well.

If you exclude that it should work. (*add a `o1 !== o2` check*)

```js
const array = [
 {start: "0", end: "3"}, 
 {start: "4", end: "6"},
 {start: "2", end: "8"}
]

checkOverlap = function(o1, o2){
  return o1 !== o2 && ((o1.end - o2.start) >= 0 && (o2.end - o1.start) >= 0) ? true : false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
   for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
      if(this.checkOverlap(array[i], array[x])){
         throw new Error("overlap detected");
      }
   }
}
```

---

Here is another approach just for the syntactic sugar of it

```js
const ranges = [
 {start: "0", end: "3"}, 
 {start: "4", end: "6"},
 {start: "5", end: "8"}
];

const overlapCheck = (A,index,arr) => arr.some(B=>A!==B && (A.start < B.end && A.end > B.start))

const isOverlap = ranges.some(overlapCheck)

console.log(isOverlap)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, essentially you checked also the type, right?

Comment: @Spartaok the type did have any involvement in the problem. The important thing is that both loops take elements from the same array which means we can check for equality.